# Error creating DirectSound buffer. Error code: 88780096

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, winamp

Sometimes Winamp shows me the following error message:

[image: Error message with the following text: Error creating DirectSound buffer. Error code: 88780096]

After that there is no audio output (just the error message) at all until I reboot the system. Is it possible to have audio again without rebooting? How could I completely avoid this kind of errors?

Environment: Windows 7, x64 on a Lenovo T420. It usually happens when I connect or disconnect and USB headset (Plantronics .Audio 655).

Comment: which version of DirectX are you using? Have you ran DirectX End User Runtime? http://tinyurl.com/7j3zvcc

Comment: @Znau: DirectX 11. No, I haven't. Should I? (It seems that it is for older DirectXs.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround: restart the *Windows Audio* Windows Service.

Source: [http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091119071014AAQN2Iy](https://web.archive.org/web/20091202230905/http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091119071014AAQN2Iy)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

- Open Winamp preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
- Go to plug-ins -> output
- Highlight DirectSound Output -> Configure
- Change device to what you have (in my case `ddj-400`)
- Same with WaveOut Output
- Restart Winamp

Answer (score 0):

88780096 = DSERR_BUFFERLOST

```
// The buffer memory has been lost, and must be restored
#define DSERR_BUFFERLOST                MAKE_DSHRESULT(150)
```

Update the soundcard drivers and hope this fixes it. Als disable hardware mixing:

[http://devmaster.net/forums/topic/6340-question-about-dserr-bufferlost/](https://web.archive.org/web/20120805004715/http://devmaster.net/forums/topic/6340-question-about-dserr-bufferlost/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've updated the drivers with no success. How can I disable hw mixing? (I've also updated the question a little bit.)

Comment: disable HW acceleration in the DirectSound Output plugin in WinAmp.

Comment: I've tried but unfortunately I've got the following: *Bad DirectSound driver. Please install proper drivers or select another device in configuration. Error code: 88890010*

Comment: I have no idea. Ask it in the Winamp forum.

Answer (score -1):

Restore the settings in your Sound Manager/audio manager, say Realtek Audio manager, to rectify this error and then restart your computer.